# Android- Null Pointer Exception in Implementing Interfaces during Communicating with Other Fragments

Tags: java, android, interface, android-fragments

Been trying to implement [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). There are errors during the `selId.onIdSelected(pid.toString())`, and getting null pointer exception on this. I think I am not sure on what is the next thing to do. I am sure that when I click the current position has data but sending it to the other fragment is another thing.

```
  public  static class SectionFragment extends ListFragment {
     OnSelectedIdListener selId;

      public interface OnSelectedIdListener {
            public void onIdSelected(String position);
        }


        public void IdSelected(String id) {
            selId.onIdSelected(id);
        }

      public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            try {
                 selId = (OnSelectedIdListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.d("error!: ",
                        String.format(e.toString(), "helow"));
            }
      }  

      ....

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            if(pid!=null){
                   Log.d("if not null here", "pid? "+ pid.toString());
                   selId.onIdSelected(pid.toString());
               }
            else{Log.d("Null selected id", ""+position);}

              }
  }
```

**Fragment B**

```
public class PlayerFragment extends ListFragment implements
                 SectionFragment.OnSelectedIdListener{

                @Override
                public void onIdSelected(String position) {
                    setSelectedId(position);
                }

}
```

Comment: make sure you are initializing `selId` or put a null check for it.

Comment: @Abu, thank you. I am doing it correctly in some way? not sure what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is good to follow naming conventions. The interface names begin with a capital letter and the method names begin with a small letter. So it's `OnSelectedListener` and `idSelected` respectively.
2. While using listener, you should always check whether the listener is not `null`.
3. You are implementing the interface in the `Fragment` whereas in your code, you are casting the `Activity` as the listener.

Comment: Thank your for that sir. Your example code would help me further understand your explanation. Thanks for considering.